# How to automatically refresh access token in ASP.NET Core MVC app

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, jwt, asp.net-core-2.0

I have a Web API backend that has an authentication endpoint for retrieving both the access and refresh token. My client already retrieves the access token and creates a new identity to sign in the user, using the `HttpContext`.

But how do I automatically get a new access token using the refresh token in my ASP.NET MVC client.

I already have the entire backend working for this part.

I've tried adding the Bearer authentication scheme to my client' services.
Now I'm using the Cookie authentication scheme.

Adding the authentication to the service:

```
services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddCookie(options => { options.LoginPath = "/Home/Index"; });
```

And here is how I log the user in:

```
var token = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Token>(result);

AuthenticationProperties options = new AuthenticationProperties()
            {
                AllowRefresh = true,
                IsPersistent = true,
                ExpiresUtc = DateTimeOffset.FromUnixTimeMilliseconds(token.Expiry),
            };

// TODO: new claim for the user name
var claims = new[]
            {
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, dto.Email),
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, dto.Role),  
                new Claim("AccessToken", $"Bearer {token.AccessToken}"),
            };

var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, "ApplicationCookie");
var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);

HttpContext.SignInAsync(principal, options);
```

Maybe this isn't the best way to authenticate my client but It worked so far.

I need the back-end and client to be separated because a mobile client also uses the same back-end.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Here is tutorial: https://www.blinkingcaret.com/2018/05/30/refresh-tokens-in-asp-net-core-web-api/

Comment: I used this tutorial for my backend, but the front-end implementation is in javascript. And the reason I want to use identity is because I want to be able to use the `[Authorize]` annotation.

Comment: have solved that?